# Understanding an old handwritten document from 1840

Tags: translation, letter, handwriting, kurrent

I have some documents written in German. I can barely make out some of the words. May be someone could read or understand what kind of document this is?[image]

Comment: The seal appears to match that of the city of what is today [Hamburg-Harburg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburg-Harburg#Geschichte). (cf. the lion in the coat of arms). But the contrast is to poor to clearly see that. Can you upload an image of the seal with better contrast?

Comment: @PMF The writing clearly shows "Marburg" and the coat of arms is the Hessian Lion.

Answer (score 5):

It is a so-called "Polizeiliches Führungszeugnis", a document attesting that no criminal or political complaint had been made against the named Doctor Kramer to the Marburg police during his stay from 1833 to 1840.

> Dem Herrn Doctor der Philosophie **Kramer** dahier wird auf seinen Wunsch hierdurch bezeugt, daß während seines hiesigen Aufenthaltes von Ostern (?) 1833, bis jetzt in Beziehung auf sein Betragen, namentlich in politischer Hinsicht
> nie die geringste Klage bei der unterzeichneten Behörde vorgebracht worden ist.
> Marburg am 17ten März 1840.
> Kurfürstliche Polizei-Direktion daselbst
> (Unterschrift)

*The other document [you asked about](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72519) tells that Doctor Kramer (there spelled Krahmer, but very probably the same person) was lecturer (Privatdozent) at the Marburg university for theology and oriental languages.*

Comment: Note that even if this document very probably is about the same guy as the marriage certificate you show in the other question, the spelling of the surname is different.

Comment: I think you can remove the ? after Ostern. The first letter is definitely an "O" and the next two letters look like the last two letters of "daselbst".