# Understanding an old handwritten document (2/4)

Tags: translation, german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

Here is another document I can't read nor understand what type of document this is
I'd be very grateful for your comments[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a summons to speak to the university's rector ("Müller, *Prorektor*"), but I can't really decipher some of the key parts. It's some dreadful scrawl *(Sauklaue)*.

I'm leaving this open for others to edit.

> Herr Dr. Krahmer wird hiermit amtlich ersucht
> Sich heute Abend um 7 Uhr Behufs einer weiteren(?)
> zum [Ziele? *or* G...?] führenden(?) Unterredung über den bekannten
> Gegenstand bei dem Unterzeichneten einzufinden.
>
> Marburg den 20sten Decbr. 1838
> Müller, Prorektor

We know from your other [document](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72520/) that Dr. Krahmer lived in Marburg from 1833 to 1840.
The *Prorektor* of the University of Marburg (a *Rektor* in all but name) in 1838/39 was Julius [Müller](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Rektoren_und_Pr%C3%A4sidenten_der_Philipps-Universit%C3%A4t_Marburg#1826%E2%80%931850).