# Handwritten document 4/4

Tags: translation, german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

The last one that I have and have no idea what is it about!
[image]

Comment: If the transcriptions that you got as answers for your several handwriting questions heve helped you, please mark them as accepted and, if you like, upvote them.

Answer (score 1):

> Strengst reservirt(?)
>
> Daß der gegenwärtig in Moskau lebende
> Dr und Lec./Lic.(?)† der Theologie, Wilhelm August
> Krahmer in früheren Jahren in hiesiger
> St Jacobi Kirche wiederholt das heilige
> Abendmahl gefeiert hat, wird hirmit
> auf dem Grund des Kommunicanten-Ver-
> zeichnißes(?) sub fide pastorali bescheinigt.
>
> Göttingen, den 27. April 1841
> Hildbrand‡
> Superint[endent] Pastor St. Jacobi

†"Lec.", i.e. "Lector der Theologie", would reference his teaching activity (as per your other document of 1841: [Understanding an old handwritten document from 1850](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72519/)). Alternatively, "Lic.", i.e. "[Licentiatus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lizenziat#Deutschland) der Theologie", would reference his qualification to teach (which is mentioned in the same words in [the other document](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72519/): "Doctor philosophiae und Licentiatus theologiae").

‡Julius Hildtbrand or Hildebrand became Pastor of St. Jacobi in Göttingen in 1839: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Hildebrand

Comment: Definitely an "i" in "Lic".